Why is DATEADD function not working?
I am trying to set a default datetime value for the column "AuctionEndDate" as the datetime one month from now. I'm using sql version 8.0.36, and I wrote several attempts, including:
ALTER TABLE AuctionItems
ALTER COLUMN AuctionEndDate DATETIME DEFAULT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE());

ALTER TABLE AuctionItems
MODIFY COLUMN AuctionEndDate DATETIME DEFAULT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);

ALTER TABLE AuctionItems
MODIFY COLUMN AuctionEndDate DATETIME DEFAULT TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());

Each time, there is a red line under the function DATEADD/DATE_ADD/TIMESTAMPADD. I am brand new to sql, and I'm at a dead end. Any help would be appreciated. TIA

Perhaps need parens around the expression.

A few issues:
ALTER TABLE...ALTER COLUMN only supports a few types of column changes. Refer to the manual:
ALTER [COLUMN] col_name {
    SET DEFAULT {literal | (expr)}
  | SET {VISIBLE | INVISIBLE}
  | DROP DEFAULT
}

Notice you cannot specify the data type after the column name, and you must use SET DEFAULT, not just DEFAULT.
Pro tip: Make a habit of reading the reference documentation carefully to check syntax. I've been writing SQL for 30+ years, and I double-check the manual frequently. There's just too much detail in the syntax to keep in your head all the time.
Another issue:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html#data-type-defaults-explicit says:

The default value specified in a DEFAULT clause can be a literal constant or an expression. With one exception, enclose expression default values within parentheses to distinguish them from literal constant default values.

(emphasis mine)
This means you would declare a column with an expression default like this:
AuctionEndDate DATETIME DEFAULT (DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()))
                                ^ use parentheses            ^

However, some functions are not allowed in such expressions. The DATEADD() and GETDATE() functions are disallowed.

ERROR 3770 (HY000): Default value expression of column 'AuctionEndDate' contains a disallowed function: GETDATE.


ERROR 3770 (HY000): Default value expression of column 'AuctionEndDate' contains a disallowed function: DATEADD.

I was able to get your example to work this way:
ALTER TABLE AuctionItems 
  ALTER COLUMN AuctionEndDate SET DEFAULT (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH);

INSERT INTO AuctionItems () VALUES ();

SELECT ID, AuctionEndDate FROM AuctionItems;
+----+---------------------+
| ID | AuctionEndDate      |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2024-05-30 19:58:39 |
+----+---------------------+

